# Trouble importing python packages Visual Studio Code

Tags: python

I am on Windows 10, running python 3.8.5 and have tried installing PyPDF2 using pip. I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times using these two commands:

"python -m pip install pypdf2"
"py -3 -m pip install pypdf2"

I did this through Visual Studio code being run as my user, as well as the command prompt run as an administrator. The install goes well but I get the error, "Import 'PyPDF2' could not be resolved."

I figure this is due to the file path to the installed package not being included in the PATH system environment variable. So I used "python -m pip show pypdf2" to find the install location:

"c:\users*username*\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages"

So I added:

"c:\users*username*\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2" to my PATH environment variable for both user and system, as well as the PYTHONPATH variable.

After such actions I restarted VS Code, which again is using the python 3.8.5 environment, and still the import could not be resolved.

What am I missing? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the python environment in VSCode the same as the python you're installing the package to?

Comment: I believe so, on the bottom left where you can choose an environment for VS code it says I'm running python 3.8.5, and when I installed it I ensured it was python 3, which it was installed in the site-packages folder under python38 in my local app data, so it appears that way.

Comment: What I usually do is reload the window using the Command Palette to restart the Python extension, which will reload the modules. (might not work for you but might be worth trying)

Comment: There is possibly another python 3.8 installation that VSCode is referring to. Can you check that the path of the interpreter is something like `C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\...`?

Comment: That was it Pranav, I didn't realize but somehow my VS Code had defaulted to Anaconda3 instead of my native 3.8 environment. Changed the default interpreter back to my 3.8 directory and all is well!

Comment: If you wanted to through that into an answer, I'd like to give you your credited karma for it.

Answer (score -1):

I am using python 3.9.6. But when I typed like this in command prompt,
"pip install pypdf2"
it worked for me. Try like this sometimes it'll work.

Comment: This still did not work for me. I uninstalled and reinstalled using just pip and it still does not resolved in VS code. I ran this in the command prompt via windows as well as VS Code.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.